# MIPS .data floating point

Tags: floating-point, mips

I have declared

```
.data
ZERO    .float     0.0
```

Later in my code, I want to put the value of ZERO into $f4

What instruction do I use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to MIPS, but this should work

```
 lwc1 $f4, ZERO($0)
```

According to this [sample](http://cs.stfx.ca/~ltyang/csci-365/labs/lab3/sample.htm) :)

Or if you use pseudo-instructions ([lecture that I found](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g51csa/l09-hand.pdf)):

```
la $a0, ZERO     #Load address
l.s $f5, 0($a0)  #Load single from memory a0[0]
```

There's a special register ($zero), but I think it's only used for integer operations (I'm not sure)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, $zero is only for integers